# Java - How to Identify Mouse Clicks on Different Locations

Tags: java, user-interface, mouseevent

I'm creating a drawing application, where the user clicks on a button to select which shape to draw - node for example - and then the shape is placed where the mouse is clicked . 
I want the user to be able to click on two different "shapes" on the screen to create a link between them. 
Every node I create is added to an `ArrayList of Nodes.` I have a `for-loop` to iterate through the nodes, and I created a function contains in my class NODE:

```
boolean contains(Point point) {
    if((point.x >= centerX-radius) && (point.x <= centerX+radius) && 
            (point.y <= centerY+radius) && (point.y>=centerY-radius))
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

because `component.contains(point)` did not work, and I think I'm able to get the first node that's clicked, but I'm still struggling with identifying to two clicks the other node.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you use jquery or  javascript for this?since in both of these you can use onblur event

Comment: Create Shape-derived objects such as Rectangle2D, Polygon or Path2D, and then you can use their `.contains(Point p)` methods. For better help, post a complete [mcve].

Comment: if you have only two shapes you can refer to this link which might help you http://www.javacodex.com/More-Examples/2/6.If you have more then you need to write logic for each key even which is clumsy

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to keep an additional variable, to know if the click is first or second.. In this case, it might be useful to keep the Node selected with first click..

So, in pseudo-code:

```
Node selected;

onClick() {
    Node clicked = findNode();

    if (clicked == null || clicked == selected) {
        selected = null;
    } else
    if (selected == null) {
        selected = clicked;
    } else {
        createLine(selected, clicked);
        selected = null; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get mouse coordinates, getX() and getY() functions are used inside the onmouseClicked(MouseEvent me) function.